# How does replaceFromWith with in AdviceWithRouteBuilder

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using AdviceWithRouteBuilder in my unit tests and I'm not sure how the replaceFromWith method works. The routes I'm testing looks something like this:

```
from(FTP_ENDPOINT)
    choice()
        when(predicateA)
            to("routeA")
        when(predicateB)
            to("routeB)
        otherwise()
            to("routeC");

from("routeA")
    to(SOMEWHERE)

from("routeB")
    to(SOMEWHER)

etc...
```

My unit tests uses an AdviceWithRouteBuilder to replace the FTP_ENDPOINT with "direct:start" like this:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        replaceFromWith("direct:start);
    }
});
```

My question is, how does replaceFromWith know which endpoint to replace? I only want to replace the FTP_ENDPOINT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 routes, eg 3 x from in the code. And in the advice with, you select the first route, when you say 'get(0)', eg

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0)
```

So it will use the first route, you can use get(1) to select the 2nd route. You can also select by route id, if you assign ids to your routes.